# PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: oracle

I tried to compile the below procedure in ORACLE DATABASE but getting Error
-PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected-

Procedure --

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PendingTrailCasePropCrimeRepNw(
    lang      IN NUMBER,
    date_from IN DATE,
    date_to   IN DATE,
    cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN LANG=99 THEN
    'MURDER FOR GAIN'
  ELSE
    'ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â²ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¾ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â­ ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã¢â‚¬Â¢ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã¢â‚¬Â¡ ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â²ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¿ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¹ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¤ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã‚ÂÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¯ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¾'
  END
AS
  'MURDER FOR GAIN',
  ---- ERROR STARTS HERE---
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM=cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD   =cdmh.LANG_CD
  INNER JOIN t_final_report fnr
  ON fnr.FIR_REG_NUM       =cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fnr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD =324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD   =36
  AND fnr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_court_disposal
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE(@startdate) AND TO_DATE(@enddate)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  PENDING_BEGINNING_YEAR,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM=cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD   =cdmh.LANG_CD
  INNER JOIN t_final_report fnr
  ON fnr.FIR_REG_NUM      =cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fnr.LANG_CD         =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE(@startdate) AND TO_DATE(@enddate)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  CASES_SEND_FOR_TRIAL,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM=cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD   =cdmh.LANG_CD
  INNER JOIN t_court_disposal cd
  ON cd.FIR_REG_NUM       =cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND cd.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE(@startdate) AND TO_DATE(@enddate)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  CASES_DISPOSED,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE MINOR_HEAD_CD     =324
  AND MAJOR_HEAD_CD       =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT   > DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '10' YEAR)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  MORE_THAN_10_YEARS,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '5' YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(@enddate,INTERVAL '10' YEAR)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  MORE_THAN_5_LESS_THAN_10_YEARS,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '4' YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(@enddate,INTERVAL '5' YEAR)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  MORE_THAN_4_LESS_THAN_5_YEARS,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '3' YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(@enddate,INTERVAL '4' YEAR)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  MORE_THAN_3_LESS_THAN_4_YEARS,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '2' YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(@enddate,INTERVAL '3' YEAR)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  MORE_THAN_2_LESS_THAN_3_YEARS,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '1' YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(@enddate,INTERVAL '2' YEAR)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  MORE_THAN_1_LESS_THAN_2_YEARS,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '6' MONTH) AND DATE_ADD(@enddate,INTERVAL '1' YEAR)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  MORE_THAN_6_MONTHS_LESS_THAN_1_YEAR,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM       = cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD=324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD  =36
  AND fr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_final_report
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT   < DATE_ADD(@startdate,INTERVAL '6' MONTH)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
  )
AS
  LESS_THAN_6_MONTHS FROM dual; 

END;
```

I am new with oracle i don't know what is wrong in above procedure and how can resolve this.
Please help me to compile this. Thanks in advance

ERRORS - 
       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
       ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Try to compile small pieces of code to identify the problem, this will help to reduce the amount of code to check. Once you have e small piece of code giving an error, feel free to post it here and ask for help.

Comment: I think your alias for your case statement AS 'MURDER FOR GAIN' should be AS "MURDER FOR GAIN" i.e.double quotes rather than single quotes

Answer (score 0):

That's too long for comment so Il'll post it as an answer.

I'd advise to use select into variable instead of building such cursor from dual. So

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PendingTrailCasePropCrimeRepNw(
    lang      IN NUMBER,
    date_from IN DATE,
    date_to   IN DATE,
    cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
PENDING_BEGINNING_YEAR number;
MURDER_FOR_GAIN varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
 if LANG=99 THEN
    MURDER_FOR_GAIN := 'MURDER FOR GAIN';
  ELSE
    MURDER_FOR_GAIN := 'ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â²ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¾ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â­ ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã¢â‚¬Â¢ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã¢â‚¬Â¡ ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â²ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¿ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¹ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¤ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¥Ã‚ÂÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¯ÃƒÂ Ã‚Â¤Ã‚Â¾'
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*) into PENDING_BEGINNING_YEAR
  FROM t_crime_major_minor_heads cdmh
  INNER JOIN t_fir_registration fr
  ON fr.FIR_REG_NUM=cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fr.LANG_CD   =cdmh.LANG_CD
  INNER JOIN t_final_report fnr
  ON fnr.FIR_REG_NUM       =cdmh.FIR_REG_NUM
  AND fnr.LANG_CD          =cdmh.LANG_CD
  WHERE cdmh.MINOR_HEAD_CD =324
  AND cdmh.MAJOR_HEAD_CD   =36
  AND fnr.FIR_REG_NUM NOT IN
    (SELECT FIR_REG_NUM FROM t_court_disposal
    )
  AND fr.REG_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE(@startdate) AND TO_DATE(@enddate)
  AND cdmh.LANG_CD=@LangCd
  AND fr.PS_CD    =@PS_CD
from dual;
  ...
```